# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused within Laravel homestead

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration, homestead, laravel-artisan

Using Mac OS X and Homestead 2.2.1 with Laravel 5.2.

In terminal (within homestead in my project folder) I can do php artisan to see all the available commands. When I try to run php artisan migrate I get a connection error:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

---

I have setup a Laravel project with these **.env** settings

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=tcv
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have also tried *localhost* for DB_HOST and *root* for DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD. And all possible variations of these put together!

---

In Sequel Pro (db management application) I CAN connect with these settings

```
Host       127.0.0.1
Username   homestead
Password   secret
Database   tcv
Port       33060
```

But this database is obviously empty, because I cant migrate to it from terminal ...

As far as I can make out it is a configuration issue, since I can connect to it with Sequel Pro. But I have honestly no freaking idea what is setup wrong.

Thanks for the help !!

**EDIT**
For some reason I get the same `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error when moving my project to MAMP and running php artisan migrate.
Now I am completely lost  ...

Comment: Have you tried changing the ip address from 127.0.0.1 to localhost? I had a similar issue ages ago and that worked for me ( cant test now as not on mac )

Comment: @Adam Yes I have (like I said in the original question), doesn't change a thing. But thanks for the input...

Comment: My bad, didnt see you already tried

Comment: your app is looking for the database on the virtual machine. I assume the Sequel Pro is able to access because that's on the host machine. You have to use your actual  computer IP to access the database from homestead

Comment: @chikurubhi And what would be a correct fix? Making the app look for the database locally? HOW would I do that?

Comment: change 127.0.0.1 in the .env to your host machine IP. You can find your machine IP http://whatismyip.org/. Otherwise you can ssh to homestead and install mysql to have that local to the virtual machine.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... Did try both options

Comment: you have port 33060 or 3306?

Comment: @chikurubhi I finally found the solution.. Thanks for asking what port I use. This made me check the database.php file again and see my own mistake. Posted the solution below for future dumbasses like me!

Comment: I am using Mac and MAMP as localserver, in file `.env` i just change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost` and it works for me, thanks @Adam

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Problem**

In Laravel you have `config/database.php` where all the setup for the connection is located. You also have a `.env` file in the root directory in your project (which everyone uses for timesaving). This contains variables that you can use for the entire project.

On a standard L5 project the MySql section of `config/database.php` looks like this:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'engine'    => null,
    ],
```

**Notice there is no port set!**

Although in my `.env` file I had set `DB_PORT=33060`. But that `value (3306)` was never read into the `config/database.php`.
So don't be a dumbass like myself and forget to check the `database.php` file.

---

**FIX**
Simply add `'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),` to your config/database.php and set that value in .env like this `DB_PORT=3306`

Comment: It was the `.env` file that I had forgotten about. Thank you!

Comment: port number is present then also same issue, i am using laravel 5

Comment: @151291 At the top of my head: are you in ssh? Do you have .env?

Comment: DB_PORT=33060, you have extra 0 at the end of port number

Comment: @MahmoudAliKassem yes, the post was edited.. I don't have enough reputation to do something about it

Comment: i have port = 3306 in both files and using laravel 7 but im still having the same issue

Comment: Exactly my issue! Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem when I tried to use remote database on project hosted on localhost, and the problem actually gone when I turned strict mode off: 'strict' => false. Before that nothing could help.

Answer (score 138):

I just ran into this and found that changing this in the **.env** file from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` fixed it.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Comment: Thanks Richard Hood. It fixed my issue. And what a stupid thing from Laravel to have this issue.

Comment: WOW! It was really solved this issue for me! Thx dude! :)

Comment: FYI MAMP users... it seems when running on a MAMP server that 127.0.0.1 works, but on a MAMP PRO server it needs to be localhost!

Comment: I got the same error message when using laradock.io (Laravel 8). Then I needed to set my real IP-adress of my computer. I guess it was due to the request came from inside the PHP-fpm container.

Comment: This fixed my issue on a live server, shared hosting. my website was running fine until after a few weeks it went down by itself, and by doing this, it fixed it but i do not know how this exactly works.

Comment: After making this change, you may get the error similar to `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` and if you search on stackoverflow, people will suggest to use `127.0.0.1` instead. This is deadlock then. I faced this issue and tried to search from the MySQL side and found one answer which fixed it. Check this out here: https://serverfault.com/a/337928

Basically you are telling MySQL to use TCP protocol by setting `protocol=tcp` in `my.cnf` file. Then you can use `127.0.0.1` in your Laravel config and things will run normally.

Comment: This actually worked for me on my production server. quite odd

Answer (score 44):

If you are using MAMP on a mac OS add the following line to your mysql database config file

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```

and on your .env file add

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Solved my problem on Catalina. Thank you

Comment: Client was testing on MAMP - this was a huge timesaver - thanks!!!

Comment: For me (Mac and MAMP) only this one worked, But very important after adding that line you should clear cache using `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: still work on last mamp version with laravel 9 (jun - 2022)

Answer (score 33):

Use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` (in your **.env** file), then run command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: This was my solution. The old password was still in cache from the old .env file.

Comment: I get "No such file or directory" when using `localhost`. I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql database forwarded via SSH.

Comment: Thank you for the command: `php artisan config:cache`. It fixed my issue.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, I get the same message. Don't you remember how to solve this? lol

Answer (score 22):

**If you have your backend and database started on docker**

Instead of putting localhost or 127.0.0.1  as DB_HOST put the name of the registered service that indicates your database service in the docker-compose file.

In my case for example I replaced 127.0.0.1 with db because in my docker-compose file I had defined the name of the service for the database as db

My docker-compose looks something like that

```
services:
    db: <------ This is the name of the DB_HOST
      container_name: admin_db
      image:mysql:5.7.22
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 18):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had the same problem and fixed just by converting DB_HOST constant in the .env File FROM `127.0.0.1` into `localhost`

JUST DO THIS AS GIVEN IN THE BELOW LINE

`DB_HOST = localhost`.

No need to change anything into `config/database.php`

Don't forget to run

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I made a PR to add some explanation for this in official Laravel documentation but they decide to ignore it. [link](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/6159)

Comment: some times this will not be worked. so you have to remove some files from here.

/bootstrap/cache/packages.php
/bootstrap/cache/services.php
/bootstrap/cache/config.php

after that run the php artisan config:clear

Comment: php artisan config:clear solved my problem on azure with nginx, laravel 8 and php 8.

Answer (score 15):

Another solution for anyone else who has a problem. I had all the settings correct but for some reason my changes weren't updated. Laravel actually caches the config file (which I find completely stupid).

Here was my solution after updating the configs:

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Laravel does not cache the config by default. You might have done that to speed up the application during development? See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: In development environment, `php artisan config:clear` will fix the issue. In production, you should also run `php artisan config:cache` as laravel suggests here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching.

Answer (score 10):

I was having this problem. When connecting with Sequel Pro, I need to use `33060` as the port, but in the **.env** file it has to be `3306`. I had `33060` in the **.env** file. Changed it to `3306` and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me. Strangely enough I have another project that I just ran before this one and that did work on 33060 while this one really needed 3306

Answer (score 9):

This is a simple fix. Your mysql database has lost its connection to the server. If you are running a local server run this in your terminal:

```
mysqld
```

That will reconnect your database. Then (if you are using homebrew) run:

```
brew services start mysql
```

This will automatically connect your database on login.

Comment: Just wanted to let SouthernBoy know that this saved me from a long day of debugging a mistake I made!

Comment: I had to `brew install mysql` Now it's working but I get a different error message instead.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was having the same error using docker and the trick was in setting in the `.env` file this `DB_HOST=db` where db is the name of the container running the database server.

Comment: This is the proper solution for those of u running their code on a Docker/Laradock mysql container. The value for DB_HOST is equal to the container hostname (ie. id) which Docker then translates to the proper network address.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that your `mysql` hasn't started or is not to the port `3306`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, try this works

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case this error appeared out of blue. While staring at that mysterious error I've realized, that I was trying to run the command outside of vm...

Comment: Trying to connect outside of the container, in my case... :(

Answer (score 3):

After you put all configuration on **.env** file, if you already run `php artisan serve`, **RESTART IT**.

Comment: This was the simple fix I needed. I change the .env file for DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, cleared config & cache but it still wasn't working. Restarting via this command worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me enclosing the credentials in quotes did the trick

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE='zzz'
DB_USERNAME='yyy'
DB_PASSWORD='XXX'
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

When Laravel connects to mysql on **Homestad** box and **running commands on local environment**:

`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`
the app needs `DB_PORT=3306`
the migrations need `DB_PORT=33060` otherwise gives `Connection refused`
phpunit needs `DB_PORT=33060` otherwise gives `Connection refused`

`DB_HOST=localhost`
the app works with both `DB_PORT=3306` or `DB_PORT=33060`
migrations cannot run
phpunit cannot run

Have in mind that phpunit takes its values from the `.env.testing` file, if exists, otherwise from the `phpunit.xml` file on the root folder of the app

Answer (score 1):

Me, Im using vagrant, yet im executing php artisan outside the box so basically it doesn't have permission

Comment: Is this a constructive answer or another question?

Comment: its an answer based on my situation

Comment: This answer is correct for me, I did forgot to login to vagrant ssh first.... migrating from my local machine surely won't work...

Answer (score 1):

I could be because you might have **not restarted PHP artisan since long**

So After making DB changes and config:clear Tinker works fine

But to make browser refect the new DB connection you need to re-run

> php artisan serve

Answer (score 1):

1. terminate sqld from task manager
2. stop MySQL from xampp control panel and restart it

if it still throw the same problem, from root folder run

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan serve
```

3. if you still have the problem, check whether you are using multiple copies of sql server, for example through Ubuntu app, if so stop the MySQL server in ubuntu

   sudo service MySQL stop

Answer (score 1):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=8080
DB_DATABASE=flap_safety
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```

the above given is my .env

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
       // 'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8080'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysql'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

the above given is my database.php file. i just commented out port from database.php and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Homestead` then you should be running it with the default mysql port. So instead of using `DB_PORT=33060`, you should be using `DB_PORT=3306` in your .env file. Also, remember to run your `php artisan migrate` commands in your homestead installation and everything should be ok.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that solved it for me was to put the connection details in **config/database.php** instead of the **.env** file. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and no suggestions placed here helped me.
This what has fixed my problem was to set the application name and database hostname with the same value. In my case, 127.0.0.1 works correctly.

```
APP_URL=127.0.0.1

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=zzz
DB_USERNAME=yyy
DB_PASSWORD=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay update it seems the host is not the issue but actually the port.

So its actually the port **3306** for the browser testing and yet for terminal and Sequel Pro **33060**. Could it have something to do with adding it in the Homestead.yaml and set it here?

On reading the setup in relation to Laravel it says:

MySQL: **33060** → Forwards To **3306**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
>   projects)

The cause was that I had not started the MySQL server.

It may help to check that the MySQL is running as the first step in troubleshooting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my server just needed to be restarted and **"bam"** it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Homestead like I do, do not forget to ssh into it before running **artisan test** for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it even reads config/database.php.
As soon as edited my entries into .env file it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone in the future... I have to run artisan commands and so on using WSL but MySQL lives on my Windows environment. I struggle with the correct terminology but my brain says **"I don't care if you think you're a virtual machine, you're quite literal and literally right in front of me so when I say connect to yourself I expect you to do so."**

If I understand correctly, PHP is executing the commands in magical WSL-land so it needs the IP of the database in relation to WSL-land.

From a command prompt (Windows, not in WSL) I ran `ipconfig` to find my IPv4 and put that for my Laravel DB_HOST. Now, when I migrate in WSL it works.

I realize this was overly wordy but I personally get very confused with all of the virtual machine stuff, so I put the answer I wish I'd found weeks ago.

*Wish I'd never gone back to Windows.*

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a fix to the solution as another way round it, but it's also possible (and much faster) to use SQLite as a database instead of MySQL, simply uncommenting the following lines in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have any kind of `proxy` or `vpn` , turn them off and close them . it was my problem .

Answer (score -3):

On ubuntu/linux you can try to restart mysql with this command: `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: OP is on MacOS. Also, why would restarting fix this?