# Laravel: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using Vagrant with fresh laravel 5.4 installed. After I run auth I have ran the migrate to migrate the MySQL tables. All of these process successful but when I try to login or register to test the system I am getting error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.

But my database working perfect since I already able to migrate the tables. Whats possible solution could be? check attached image (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04)

[image: Connection refused.]

Comment: Did you also check if the tables are really created in phpmyadmin? (if you're running that) and is the mysql server on the same server as the code?

Comment: yea i am using phpstrom (built in database manager) and i have configured the same db with it. so i have checked all tables has created successfully

Comment: please share your .env file code

Comment: Check screenshot from here- https://expirebox.com/download/741543100157daa4d14c2b49bcb8ccdf.html

Comment: Can you verify whether MySQL is listening on port 33060? Since the default port is 3306. Laravel Homestead uses the former by default so it is possible that the issue has something to do with that. Or are you using Homestead?

Comment: yes i am using Homestead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] Connection refused within Laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try changing your DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost. and if still not working try using the default mysql port to 3306

Comment: Changing from 127.0.0.1 to localhost worked for me! Thankss

Comment: Changing from 127.0.0.1 to localhost worked for me. But is there any difference between `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` here?

Comment: There is a nice answer for that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382629/4668162 @GhulamAkbar

Comment: I am using Docker, and using: DB_HOST=mysql worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you use laravel maybe your PDO PHP Extension not set.
in your php.ini uncomment extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

if you had no access to php.ini do this:
add this to config/database.php in mysql section

```
'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true],
```

your code should be like this:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true],
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run php artisan migrate from host machine you need to set in .env conf file DB_PORT=33060 as that is a port vagrant/Homestead is listening on. But when i change that my application stop working.
So i suggest ssh to vagrant and run php artisan migrate from VM and you will have no problems.