# Laravel migration "No such file or directory"

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I started working with Laravel recently and followed every step from this tutorial: 
https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

For now I create the model and configured the `.env` and `database` files.

`.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bank
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

For me everything seems correct, MyPhpAdmin is running and I have added a bank database to it.

But every time I try to migrate I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = bank and table_name = migrations)

Comment: Have you tried running `composer update`?

Comment: did you install php-pdo extension ?

Comment: did you try this? (`composer dump-autoload`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686135/php-artisan-migrate-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php artisan migrate no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686135/php-artisan-migrate-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help i ran "composer update" (now on laravel version5.7.9) and composer dump-autoload but its still giving me the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

This looks unrelated to Laravel, I think it's to do with PHP not being able to connect to MySQL correctly. See here - [PHP - MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I changed my default socket in the php.ini file to pdo_mysql.default_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock and restarted my Apache but its still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I add DB_SOCKET in .env file refer to my.cnf (socket) then run php artisan migrate. It works!

DB_SOCKET=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

And double check your config/database.php, comment or delete if there are other **unix_socket** except this 'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '')