# Connection refused: Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite, connection, migration

"**SQLSTATE**[HY000] [2002] **Connection refused** (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
  where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)"

**database.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

**migrations**

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: did you set database access in `.env` file?

Comment: Please also provide some context. What is it that you want to achieve? Where are the issues? What have you tried? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: error is in connection.php and connector.php

Comment: Possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .env file:

`DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`

and

`config/database.php` file:

replace

`'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),`

with

`'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),`

From https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Comment: @Bibek please provide more details. Error messages, line of code that is experiencing the error.