# How to verbose artisan commands? -- always getting PDO connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-artisan

In a Laravel app at EC2 instance deployed by Elastic Beanstalk I'm getting this error for any of artisan command.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-31-44-192 ondeck]$ sudo php artisan -vvv

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Running echo on my DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD, I can see all variables are correctly defined.

How can I better debug this?

Comment: run `php artisan config:cache` and try again

Comment: @Stranger this command returns the same error =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] Connection refused within Laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)

Comment: not a duplicate cuz I'm not at homestead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

artisan calls app/Console/Kernel.php schedule() method in each command. So if you have some errors there - you'll see it in artisan output. Check is it a reason

Comment: tried to add echo env('DB_HOST') in schedule() method, but nothing appears at console