# Can't php artisan migrate - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When running php artisan migrate, It gives following error message

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
>         /Users/redblac/olivertes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> 2
>   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=oliverte",
>   "root", "", [])
>         /Users/redblac/olivertes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

Turkish language

EDIT: Çözüm - Veritabanında password no özellikli yeni bir kullanıcı oluşturdum ve mamp kullandığım için .env ye DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock ekledim sorun çözüldü.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead might help you

Comment: Try DB_HOST=localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you using Docker by any chance?

Comment: It is not laravel migrate issue ! It is a db connection issue ! Check your db info again and laravel env

Answer (score 2):

The exception means artisan is not able to connect to your database. Try figuring out the following things:

- Make sure you have a database up and running
- Make sure the database is not behind a firewall
- Make sure you can connect to the database via a separate [sql client](https://techtalk.gfi.com/top-10-free-database-tools-for-sys-admins/)
- Make sure you have your database credentials configured correctly in your `.env` file
- You could check out Laravel documentation on [databases](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database) and [environment configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#environment-configuration)

If you want more help on this, try providing us with some more information as to how you have setup your development environment.