# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused on Laravel Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a laravel site hosted on a server and when I log in, it usually load but today i see that it says connection refused.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin12345@gmail.co.za limit 1)
```

has anyone experienced this?

my env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME='root'
DB_PASSWORD='123456789'

I have changed `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=localhost` but still no success
```

Comment: Why have a single quote like this `DB_USERNAME='root'` when you can just add `DB_USERNAME=root`

Comment: Not sure if it will fix the issue, but the .env may not recognize the `'` as a quote and try to parse it

Comment: @DevinGray the program refuses to run if the quotes are not there

Comment: can you try with `DB_USERNAME="root"`

Comment: @DevinGray password too?

Comment: Yes, I know in my .env I always use double quotes, if not working after that then the error is somewhere else

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @DevinGray Still no result

Comment: Lets start a chat I can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231728/discussion-between-devin-gray-and-juststartedcoding).

Comment: you can try `php artisan config:cache` to clear the cache of config.

Comment: did you install PHP pdo_mysql?

Comment: @TuranZamanlı no i have not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead

Comment: @TuranZamanlı i have the port numbers included, but still nothing works

Comment: Did you check your mysql connection with terminal ? or with telnet ?

Comment: it seems my sql needs to be restarted but it refuses to saying unit not found

Comment: @TuranZamanlı 
Unit mssql-server.service could not be found.

Comment: you need to instal MySQL, not mssql.